# Trying to query contacts for detailed information.

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to query the Contacts database for contacts information, I have designed the program in a way that only contacts with Birth Day details are fetched:

```
projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,

        };

        where = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;


        selectionArgs = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
```

The Call:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

And Finally I try to fetch the result:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, where,
            selectionArgs, null);
    return loader;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Map<Date,String> BD = new HashMap<Date,String>(); 

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+id, 10000).show(); 

        String displayBirthday = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


        String DateStr=displayBirthday;
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", current).parse(DateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
        BD.put(d1, name); 
    }
    TreeMap Sorted = new TreeMap<Date,String>(BD); 
    //new MagicCall().execute(Sorted); 
}
```

However I do not get the phone number, it gives me the birth day field result in the toast message instead of the phone number, if I change it to email it still gives me the birthday detail. Please neglect the suppress warnings as this is a test project in which I have isolate the problem code.

Answer (score 0):

try with this dude :) best of luck

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

and this is code of class

```
public class ReadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private ListView contactsList;

    private Context cntx;
    private Constant constants;

    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, // 0
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
        Contacts.STARRED, // 2
        Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED, // 3
        Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE, // 4
        Contacts.PHOTO_ID, // 5
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, // 6
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, // 7
    };

    private long contactId;
    private String display_name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    private ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>contactWrap = new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>();
    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>();

    private ContactsAdapter adapter;

    private DataController controller;

    public ReadContacts(Context cntx, ListView contactList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx = cntx;
        constants = new Constant();
        this.contactsList = contactList;

        controller = DataController.getInstance(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
             constants.displayProgressDialog(cntx, "Loading Contacts...", "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
        {
        try {
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

            Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

            int colorcounter = 0;
            String[] colorcounter_array = { "#91A46B", "#8BB6B5", "#CAA973", "#8DA6C8","#D19B8D"};

            int color_string;
            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
            {
//              contactWrap.clear();
                try {
                    contactId = 0;
                    String hasPhone = "";
                    display_name = "";
                    phoneNumber = "";

                    c.moveToPosition(i);

                    contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                    display_name = c.getString(1);
                    hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;

                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                            String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                            String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                            if (colorcounter < 5) 
                            {
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            } else {
                                colorcounter = 0;
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            }
                            contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                        }
//                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                        phones.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
            controller.contactWrapper = contactWrap;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        constants.dismissDialog();

        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(cntx);
        contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

and this is my contact wrapper class

```
public class ContactsWrapper {

private long contactId;
private String displayName,displayNumber,lookUp;
public boolean checked = true;
int color_string;

public ContactsWrapper(long contactId, String displayName, String displayNumber, String lookUp, boolean checked,int color_string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
    this.lookUp = lookUp;
    this.checked = checked;
    this.color_string =color_string;
}

public String getLookUp() {
    return lookUp;
}

public int getColor_string() {
    return color_string;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public long getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public String getDisplayNumber() {
    return displayNumber;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

dont panic dude just match  list with thar birthdate and take one temp arraylist and when any name match then add in that temp arraylist and then show that list view according to that temp arraylist :) here i give u code and hint i think it will help u to achieve whatever u want...:)

```
ArrayList<String> matchname = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(int l =0;l<contactarraylist.size();l++)
                    {
                        String keyname = contactarraylist[k];

                        if((keyname.trim().equals("birthdate_string")))
                        {
                            matchname.add(keyname);

                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: I have a different selection criteria, want to return only those contacts whose birth date is specified.

Comment: just see my last edited answer here i give u solution how to do it

Comment: Thanks @Bhanu, I am looking into the solution you provided.